# ¿Cómo enmascarar mientras se escribe en el input con ionic 2?

Tags: ionic, angularjs-2.0

Tengo unos input los cuales solicito numero de tarjeta de credito, numero de tel y zip code. Pero no sé cómo enmascarar mientras escribe. Soy novato.
Vean esta [libreria](http://candreoliveira.github.io/bower_components/angular-mask/examples/index.html#/)
Estoy utilizando:

```
Your system information:

Cordova CLI: 6.4.0 
Ionic Framework Version: 2.0.0-rc.2
Ionic CLI Version: 2.1.8
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.1.4
Ionic App Scripts Version: 0.0.43
ios-deploy version: Not installed
ios-sim version: Not installed
OS: Linux 4.7
Node Version: v6.5.0
Xcode version: Not installed
```

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { ProfesionalbPage } from '../profesionalb/profesionalb';
import { DataTest } from '../../providers/data-test';
import {FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators} from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-profesionala',
  templateUrl: 'profesionala.html'
})
export class ProfesionalaPage {
  profesionala:FormGroup;
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public datatest: DataTest, public formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
    this.profesionala=this.createMyForm();
  }

  private createMyForm(){
    return this.formBuilder.group({
      nombre:['',Validators.required],
      apellido:['',Validators.required],
      correo:['',Validators.required],
      pais:['',Validators.required],
      telefono:['',Validators.required],
      clave:['',Validators.required],
      ciudad:['',Validators.required],
      codigoPostal:['',Validators.required]
    })
  }

  btnContinuar(){
    //console.log(this.profesionala.value)
    this.datatest.nombre=this.profesionala.value.nombre;
    this.datatest.apellido=this.profesionala.value.apellido;
    this.datatest.correo=this.profesionala.value.correo;
    this.datatest.pais=this.profesionala.value.pais;
    this.datatest.telefono=this.profesionala.value.telefono;
    this.datatest.clave=this.profesionala.value.clave;
    this.datatest.ciudad=this.profesionala.value.ciudad;
    this.datatest.postal=this.profesionala.value.postal;
    this.navCtrl.push(ProfesionalbPage);
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log();
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>Registro Profesional</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>
<ion-content padding>
  <form [formGroup]="profesionala">
    <ion-list>
      <ion-row>
        <ion-col width-50>
          <ion-item>
            <ion-icon name="person" item-left></ion-icon>
            <ion-label floating>Nombre</ion-label>
              <ion-input type="text" formControlName="nombre"></ion-input>
          </ion-item>
        </ion-col>
        <ion-col width-50>
          <ion-item>
            <ion-icon name="person" item-left></ion-icon>
            <ion-label floating>Apellido</ion-label>
            <ion-input type="text" formControlName="apellido"></ion-input>
          </ion-item>
        </ion-col>
      </ion-row>
      <ion-item>
        <ion-icon name="mail" item-left></ion-icon>
        <ion-label floating>Correo</ion-label>
        <ion-input type="email" formControlName="correo"></ion-input>
      </ion-item>
      <ion-row>
        <ion-col width-50>
          <ion-item>
            <ion-icon name="person" item-left></ion-icon>
            <ion-label floating>Pais</ion-label>
            <ion-select formControlName="pais">
              <ion-option value="nes">NES</ion-option>
              <ion-option value="n64">Nintendo64</ion-option>
              <ion-option value="ps">PlayStation</ion-option>
              <ion-option value="genesis">Sega Genesis</ion-option>
              <ion-option value="saturn">Sega Saturn</ion-option>
              <ion-option value="snes">SNES</ion-option>
            </ion-select>
          </ion-item>
        </ion-col>
        <ion-col width-50>
          <ion-item>
            <ion-icon name="call" item-left></ion-icon>
            <ion-label floating>Telefono</ion-label>
            <ion-input type="tel" formControlName="telefono"></ion-input>
          </ion-item>
        </ion-col>
      </ion-row>
      <ion-item>
        <ion-icon name="lock" item-left></ion-icon>
        <ion-label floating>Contraseña</ion-label>
        <ion-input type="password" formControlName="clave"></ion-input>
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item>
        <ion-icon name="pin" item-left></ion-icon>
        <ion-label floating>Ciudad</ion-label>
        <ion-input type="text" formControlName="ciudad"></ion-input>
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item>
        <ion-icon name="code" item-left></ion-icon>
        <ion-label floating>Codigo postal</ion-label>
        <ion-input type="number" formControlName="codigoPostal"></ion-input>
      </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
    <div padding>
      <button ion-button block icon-right (click)="btnContinuar()">Siguiente<ion-icon name="log-in"></ion-icon></button>
    </div>
  </form>
</ion-content>
```

Comment: Hola Wilmer, para que podamos ayudarte deberías compartir el código que usas actualmente. Así podremos ver en qué punto estás y, a partir de allí, construir mejoras. De lo contrario la pregunta es demasiado amplia y carece de esfuerzo por tu parte.

Comment: ok ya comparto el codigo

Comment: Coloco el código aquí o por donde lo podría compartir

Comment: Aquí, aquí, [edit]a la pregunta para incluirlo.

Comment: Quiero utilizar esta <a href="http://candreoliveira.github.io/bower_components/angular-mask/examples/index.html#/">libreria</a> Pero no se como agregarla ya que en ionic 2

Comment: tu pregunta aún no queda clara

Comment: ¿Para ti qué es enmascarar?

Answer (score 0):

Creo que al decir "enmascarar" quieres decir **ocultar** lo que el usuario está escribiendo, para ello, es simple, sólo coloca `type="password"` dentro del `<ion-input>` tag.